# uncover an integer sequence where all but one values are masked by NA's

Tags: r, vector, sequence, seq

Say I have an integer vector where all but one entries are masked by `NA`'s,

```
x <- c(NA, NA, 5, NA)
```

Is there a way to unmask those `NA`'s (by in-place modification of `NA` or creating a new vector)? My desired output is

```
c(3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be

```
id <- which(!is.na(x))
newx <- seq_along(x) + (x[id] - id)
```

This works for your *all `NA`'s but one value* vector.